# Use Standard Activity Email Composer from custom LWC component

Tags: email, lightning-web-components, standard

I am working on building a native Salesforce application using LWC and would like to allow the user to send an email via standard Activity Email composer by logging it as activity similar to standard Email activity quick actions.

In the absence of a standard base web component for Email Composer, is there any way to repurpose the standard Email composer? Any help would be highly appreciated.

PFB Image - Standard Activity Email Composer
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have any similar requirement? Does anyone implement something similar before? Please do let me know if anyone of you has any inputs here. I am still looking for a point and click solution here rather than going for a custom solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of research, I come to an conclusion that at the moment there is not support provided from Salesforce Platform to invoke or use the standard email composer directly in Aura/LWC/VF page hence I choose to built a basic custom email composer which uses the [SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) class with setting to add the email sent as activity on the target record. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I quite think is not possible to use the SF composer. However, looking at the requirements and what it takes, it seems to be not too hard to make a custom one. Please take a look at the following link where they explain how to make one.

https://www.salesforcelwc.in/2019/04/create-custom-component-to-send-email.html

Comment: Thanks @Nadine for the response. Yes, i went ahead with the custom implementation only.

Comment: The linked site was previously promoted in spam; are you affiliated?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean. The link seems to be working ok and shows the desired content. I am not affiliated to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can invoke standard Email Composer To Custom Component by using both LWC/AURA.
create a LWC Component"EmailQuickAction2 "

**In  html**

```
<div> 
  <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Send an Email" onclick={handleClick}>
  </lightning-button>
</div>
```

**In JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from 'lightning/pageReferenceUtils';

export default class EmailQuickAction2 extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    handleClick() {
        var pageRef = {
            type: "standard__quickAction",
            attributes: {
                apiName: "Global.SendEmail"
            },
            state: {
                recordId: 'Place Your RecordId',
                defaultFieldValues:
                encodeDefaultFieldValues({
                    HtmlBody : "Pre-populated text for the email body.", 
                    Subject : "Pre-populated Subject of the Email"
                })
            }
        };

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](pageRef);
    }
}
```

Now Go the Object from OBJECT MANAGER where you want to do the Component.
Go the Button ,links  & Actions create a new action and call that lwc component.
Now go to page layout and add that action in the record page.

Here is the Link for Reference.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_productivity_email_composer_access.htm&release=240&type=5

Comment: It's also worth noting that this appears to have become possible in Winter '23. Serves as an important bit of context considering this question was asked in January of 2020.

Comment: Thanks for adding additional detail.

Comment: This piece of code is not working for me. The spinner is moving endlessly. Can u plz help here, is there any configuration or settings needed to be added to make it work?